# lvconvert --merge how to undo?

Tags: lvm, snapshot, libvirt

I have created a script for users who work on KVM virtual machines to be able to perform lvm snapshots on the logical volumes where their VMs are installed.  Snapshot restores are performed via `lvconvert --merge /dev/vg1/lv_snapshot`  What I want to know is, is there any easy way to unmerge the snapshot from the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when you first create the original LV, create a snapshot of it. To perform the equivalent of an unmerge you merge this snapshot.

Comment: I figured that much.  
So there is no offical undo feature then?